# Getting 302 error from IIS 10 when uploading html file

Tags: iis, iis-10

On one of our client's server we are getting **302 Object Moved** only when uploading html file. On same server I can upload other file types e.g. excel. Application is working fine on other machines so it is related to one specific server and only with html files.

The error occurs before reaching our WebApi controller.

I checked IIS log files but I think there is no entry for the request.

What should I look at to fix the issue?

Comment: Check your web.config for `requestFiltering` settings and check if your IIS is aware of the MIME type of your files.